# (Can't boot with UEFI)Can not boot window after installing linux

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, grub-efi

I recently follow others instructions to install Linux alongside window 10. While I was making the partitions for an  installation, it asked me to make a partition for EFI boots as well(a warning said EFI is missing), so I make one for it. The installation went well and I tried to go back to window after everything finished.

Now it comes with the problem that i can't go back to window although I selected UEFI boot mode and window to boot in BIOS and bring me back to Linux. The boot page only shows a list of EFI options which are Ubuntu and Window Boot Manager, but I am wondering that window should boot with UFEI mode but not the EFI and that's confusing me.

My window should be installed in C drive, and I installed Ubuntu in D drive. Does it effect or damage Window when this happened?

I am a newbie about this, please any suggestion will help. Thank you!

Comment: @Melebius I just realized I missed one of the guys said convert EFI to UEFI, but it seems that I have to reinstall the Linux. I will get it a go first.

Comment: EFI is almost the same as [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface), these terms are used as synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your windows partition should be intact unless you deleted that.

I faced kind of same issues when I dual booted my system.

Make sure to install Linux in the same mode windows is installed (Legacy or UEFI), otherwise you won't be able to boot into windows.
If you've already done the same and somehow grub is unable to map windows partition.

Try running these command, it'll repair any bootloader issues if there are any.

`sudo update-grub`

If still stuck, try diagnosing this issue from here if you installed ubuntu like distro - [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

If you've installed Linux in UEFI mode and unable to boot into windows, performing a clean install of linux in legacy mode will be more preferable for you.

Comment: I think my window boot with UEfI and I install Linux with EFI, so I can't boot window now. I do try the update grub  command and boot repair command but it still not working. Also I can't see my window when I run the grub update cmd

Comment: You can only have one ESP - efi system partition per drive. So if installer wanted another, Windows was not UEFI or you had corrupt ESP. You cannot mix UEFI & BIOS on same drive. Post in original question above a link to the summary report from Boot-Repair, so we can confirm details.

Comment: I am so sorry for the late reply. here is the link from the boot repair
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/g5PxBJDBHT/